# Android Keyboard "Show correction suggestions"

Tags: android, android-source

I am trying to programmatically set the default value of "Show correction suggestions" in the language and input settings from "Always show" to "Always hide". If I can get some pointers as to how to make this changes from the AOSP code itself I'll be very grateful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

navigate to packages\inputmethods\LatinIme\javaj\res\values\donottranslate.xml

< string name="prefs_suggestion_visibility_show_value">0< / string>

< string name="prefs_suggestion_visibility_show_only_portrait_value">1< /string>

< string name="prefs_suggestion_visibility_hide_value">2< / string>

look for this entry;
< string name= "prefs_suggestion_visibility_default_value">1< / string>

replace 1 with any of the preference value you want